# How to fetch the user if all subjects are passed by using hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on hibernate by using criteria api ,I have **Student and Subjects** two entities is there ,**Student have one to many relationship with subjects** ,in Subjects table I have one column as **result** ,Now I want to write the query if Student passed all subjects(based on the result column ) I want to fetch that user other wise I don't want to return any  user.How to write Criteria query for this.

```
@Entity(name="student")
public class Student
{
    @column(name="Id")
    private int id;

    @column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Subject> subject = new ArrayList<Subject>();

 //setter getter methods
}

@Entity(name="subject")
public class Subject
{
    @column(name="Id")
    private int id;

    @column(name="subject_name")
    private String subjectName;

    @manytoOne
    @Joincolumn(name="student_id")
    private Suduent suduent;

    @column(name="result)
    private String result;
 //setter getter methods
}
```

please check below sample data 
**Student :**

```
Id------Name

1-------Test

2------Test2
```

**Subjects**

```
Id ---- Subject_Name ------ Result------   StudnetId

1------Java------------------pass---------1

2-------.net----------------fail---------1

3-------Java---------------pass---------2

4--------.net------------pass ---------2
```

Any one help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I will try to answer your query from what I undertood
1. **Criteria can only select projections, or the root entity.**
2. The below code snippet should work for you to retrieve students with result as "pass".(I assume you store this as value in result when student passes the subject)

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class, "student");
criteria.createAlias("student.subject", "subject ");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("subject.result", "pass");
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

3. HQL will be better and simpler for you, try the below HQL .. 
   Again I am making assumption about 'pass' as result.

   select distinct student from Student student 
   join student.subject subject
   where subject.result = 'pass'

Answer (score 2):

For Your requirement "if Student passed all subjects" then return the student id

I guess you are trying to pass only students who have passed in all the subjects.So the sql query will look something like this:

SQL Query:

```
select student_id
from subject a
where result="pass"
group by student_id
having count(subject_id) = (
    select count(subject_id)
    from subject
    where student_id = a.student_id
    group by student_id
)
```

In Hibernate Criteria you can't actually do having count(subject_id), and hence you will have to manually pass the no of subjects that all students must have passed.

Code :

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Subject.class,"subQuery");
dc.createAlias("student", "student");
dc.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
dc.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("student.id","outerQuery.student.id"));

Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Subject.class,"outerQuery");
query.createAlias("student", "student");
query.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("student.id"))
                        .add(Projections.count("id"))
               );

query.add(Restrictions.eq("result","pass"));
// The total number of subjects has to be passed explicitly.
query.add(Subqueries.eq(new Long(2), dc));
```